# Bike sharing data with customer ID

Tags: data-request, time-series, bikesharing

Is there any bike sharing dataset available that **INCLUDES a customer ID** (not only a bike ID)?

Comment: CustomerID with geo-coordinates would be a big privacy breach (e.g. you see where people live, work and where they go)

Comment: Actually geo-coordinates would be neglectable (for privacy reasons) as the focus would be to be able to analyze the usage behavior of sharing services.

Comment: Here is a data source you may want to dig into further.  I have not verified any of the data, but the project looks like what you are talking about. http://vartree.blogspot.com/2014/04/i-know-where-you-were-last-summer.html

Comment: The distinction between customer ID and bike ID only makes sense for repeat users. You keep stressing that Bike ID *won't do the trick* - why not?

Comment: And what kind of data should be in the set? You specify **exactly zero** (we could make some wild guesses since the tag is *time-series*, but that's it).

Comment: To be able to analyze the individual renting behavior. The insights from analyzing data that only includes "bike IDs" is rather limited.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a long list of **[Bikeshare programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle-sharing_systems)**

And here is a github list of Bikeshare programs with data sharing

**[Bike Share Data Systems](https://github.com/BetaNYC/Bike-Share-Data-Best-Practices/wiki/Bike-Share-Data-Systems)**

---

(But it will be up to you to go through and find one suitable to your needs.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good set of data available from http://hubwaydatachallenge.org/

> The Hubway trip history data includes every trip taken through Nov
>   2013 – with date, time, origin and destination stations, plus the bike
>   number and more.

Comment: Thanks. However, the question was about a dataset with customer ID.

Comment: I guess this doesn't have a specific customerID associated with the data, however it does have a "BikeID" that could potentially be used as a surrogate, depending on your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately, bikeID won't do the trick.